# The APP works in emulator but not in real phone

Tags: android

my APP is voice chat between server and client. client side works well. but server side doesn't work on real phone but in emulator.

it shows no error sometimes.

whats wrong with my code?

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private Button receiveButton,stopButton;
private TextView receive_label;
private EditText port;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
private AudioTrack speaker;
private int port_num=50005;



//private int sampleRate =8000;//Integer.parseInt(audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));   
private int channelConfig =  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;    
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       
int minBufSize=4096;

private boolean status = true;



@SuppressLint("NewApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    receiveButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.receive_button);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);
    receive_label= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receive_label);
    receiveButton.setOnClickListener(receiveListener);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(stopListener);
    port=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

   //AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  //  sampleRate =Integer.parseInt( audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));
}


private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        status = false;
        speaker.release();
        Log.d("VR","Speaker released");

    }

};


private final OnClickListener receiveListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        status = true;

        receive_label.setText("socket...1");
        startReceiving();

    }

};

public void startReceiving() {

    Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                  DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(50005);
                  Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");


                  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];


                  for (int sampleRate : new int[] {8000, 11025, 16000, 22050,
                          32000, 37800, 44056, 44100}) {  // add the rates you wish to check against

                      minBufSize = 4096;//AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                      if (minBufSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {

                          speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                          speaker.play();
                      }
                  }


                  //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
                 // int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);


                            while(status == true) {

                                  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                                  socket.receive(packet);
                                  Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");

                                  //reading content from packet
                                 buffer=packet.getData();
                                  Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                                  //sending data to the Audiotrack obj i.e. speaker
                                  speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                                 Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");
                        }

                        } catch (SocketException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }




                }


    });
    receiveThread.start();
}}
```

give me your best help

Comment: You are trying to bypass some permissions with this 'StrictMode...' code? It's not usual and it may be a problem.

Comment: yes.so whats your solution?

Comment: Usually if your app needs some permission, you just declare it in manifest file, so remove this line check logcat for security exception. This give you information what permission you need to add.

Comment: i removed the StrictMode.run the APP No error !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run both apps in same local network